# How to select tab bar item without selecting it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using swift and I have a problem with the tab bar. I want to select a tab bar item, but without open it, what I mean: I want to change its color like it is selected but without the selection is it possible to be done. Here is a image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLLvB.jpg , I want the top left item (burger menu item) color to be like the first one and the first one color to be light (like not selected).

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the image of the item you want to highlight (selecting without selecting).

You can try something like this:

```
let image = shouldHighlight ? UIImage(named: "highlightItem") : UIImage(named: "normalStyle")

 myViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "text", image: image, selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedImage"))
```

Then you update the viewControllers property in you tab bar viewController

```
myTabViewController.viewControllers
```

Comment: can you give me some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-select the tabBar item
like this:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 //select whatever You want
```

and 
colorTint the unselected index

```
tabBar = UITabBarController()

tabBar?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white //bar Color
            tabBar?.tabBar.tintColor = .red //Icons color
            tabBar?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .white //Unselected item Colors
```

Comment: yes, but this selected index is selecting the item and open its content, I don't want to do this action

Comment: use tabBar?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .white

Comment: is it posible only for one item, not for all

Comment: @Ray you need to code for one item, or modify the image and change it when you selected